# Fraction Brackets size

Tags: fractions

I wanted to write the following equation but somehow my first bracket before the fraction is shorter, last one is fine. but I have no clue what happened to the first one,

also is it possible to write the stuffs under sup as two separate lines, rather than in one line?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}

\Lambda \left( \phi \right) \coloneqq  \adjustlimits\sup_{x,y \in E, x \neq y} \left({\dfrac{ d \left( \phi \left(x\right) , \phi \left(y\right) \right) } {d \left(x, y \right)} } \right) 

\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You shouldn't use `\adjustlimits` in this case; no blank lines inside `aligned` either.

Comment: but then how shall I write under supremum??, actually that is why I used adjust limits....sorry to ask again

Comment: Try without it! For the two lines, write `\sup_{\substack{x,y\in E\\ x\neq y}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\adjustlimits` macro of `mathtools` is used for getting vertically aligned limits when two operators taking limits follow one another. In this case it's exactly the reason why `\left(` doesn't do what it's supposed to.

When in a display, `\sup` behaves exactly like `\lim`, so there's no special thing to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Lambda(\phi) \coloneqq  \sup_{\substack{x,y \in E\\ x \neq y}}
  \left( \dfrac{d(\phi(x), \phi(y))}{d(x, y)}\right) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\left` and `\right` are necessary only around the fraction (but in this case I'd omit those parentheses altogether).

Also `aligned` is not necessary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks sorry I made a stupid mistake again, but finally worked

Comment: @ShaikhTanvirHossain Put `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}` in the document preamble and use `\argmax` in the document.

Comment: Ah! ok...Thanks man, many thanks...I was deleting my question, thought you might not check again......really appreciate this

Comment: so my question was ...(sorry I deleted it)  !!Sorry @egreg I got another similar problem, couldn't solve, rather than \sup now I have \arg\max, problem is now stuff below is coming under max, can I make it in center?? –